# Does carrot juice cure cancer?

Tags: medical-science, nutrition

Ann Cameron, author of “[Curing Cancer with Carrots](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Curing-Cancer-Carrots-Ann-Cameron/dp/0692521763/)”, claims that her cancer was cured by carrot juice, and recommends it as a treatment to others, as a potential substitute for chemotherapy.

> I followed Ralph Cole’s protocol, which he developed by experimentation with quantities. He found that juicing three pounds of carrots daily stopped his tumors from growing but didn’t eliminate them. After he increased his juicing to five pounds of carrots daily, his small tumors (eight of them, each about the size of a grain of rice) disappeared entirely in eight weeks. On the evidence of Ralph’s experience, I juiced five pounds of carrots daily for close to eight months. After seven weeks of carrot juicing, a CT showed that the tumors between my lungs had stopped growing and had shrunk slightly. At four months, they were no longer visible on CT and my lungs were normal.
>
> ...
>
> Carrot juicing can enhance the positive effects of radiation and chemotherapy and reduce their damages. To play it safe, one can use radiation and chemo and carrot juice at the same time. But **because chemotherapy is toxic, if an oncologist says a delay in starting chemo will not greatly increase one’s risks, I would recommend a person newly diagnosed with cancer try carrot juice alone first for a period of six weeks**, and then to get a CT scan. If at that point there’s been growth in the cancer, I’d recommend adding chemotherapy or another treatment to continued carrot juice drinking.

[The Anti-Cancer Properties of Carrots](https://reset.me/story/the-anti-cancer-properties-of-carrots/)

Is the consumption of carrot juice a cure for cancer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, there is no evidence to support this claim, because she is claiming to have cured a cancer that was never diagnosed.

Via [Dr David Goski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Gorski)'s [Respectful Insolence blog](https://scienceblogs.com/insolence/2013/10/15/chris-beat-cancer-he-did-indeed-but-it-wasnt-quackery-that-cured-him):

> For example, Ann Cameron claims to have cured herself of stage IV colon cancer with carrot juice. She had stage III colon cancer, underwent surgery, and refused chemotherapy. Later, she was noted to have lesions in her lungs suspicious for metastases. These supposedly disappeared with carrot juice. However, there is no record of any of these lesions having been biopsied. A PET scan showed "spots" that looked like lymph nodes, but again there is no mention of these lesions ever having been biopsied. My conclusion? These almost certainly were not metastatic cancer.

So she is claiming that carrot juice cured a cancer that she claimed appeared *after* the cancer that was successfully treated with surgery.

Comment: This answer may be incomplete but I am snowed under at work right now. I did find some vague refutation on the general claim on Cancer Research UK, but not specific enough to include here. In any case, it seems the writer didn't actually have the cancer she claims to have cured with carrot juice.

Comment: And even if it happened as described: drinking a lot of carrot juice while your cancer disappears does not equal "cured through juice"

Comment: And even if it actually cured her cancer it is no proof that it can cure any other cancer (cancer is not one disease, but several thousand different diseases, possibly even a specific type only found in one patient).